# Cannot access member arrays in Prisma model with a relational table. Using next.js, prisma, typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, prisma

I have two tables defined with a relationship.  Categories and Articles.  Prisma build the relationship and all that looks good. Here is the definition of the Category table.

```
model Category {
  id       Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  parentId Int?
  name     String    @unique
  articles Article[]
}

model Article {
  id              Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  date            DateTime  @default(now())
  title           String    @unique
  summary         String    @db.Text
  text            String    @db.MediumText
  userId          String
  user            User      @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  categoryId      Int
  category        Category  @relation(fields: [categoryId], references: [id])
  image           String?
  tags            String?
  commentsEnabled Boolean   @default(true)
  comments        Comment[]
  likes           Like[]
}
```

When I query the categories from Prisma, I do it like this:

```
const categories = await prisma.category.findMany(
    {
        include: {
            articles: true
        },
        orderBy: {
            name: 'asc'
        }
    }
);
```

When the app runs, I can see the Category model has the articles object array in it. Here is that part.

```
{
  "id": 4,
  "parentId": 2,
  "name": "....",
  "articles": [
    {
      "id": 13,
      "date": "....",
      "title": "....",
      "summary": " ....",
      "userId": "....",
      "categoryId": 4,
      "image": null,
      "tags": null,
      "commentsEnabled": true
    }
  ]
}
```

In short -- I have an array of Category objects.  Each of those contains an array of Article objects.  The data gets returned, as demonstrated above.  Inspecting the categories array I can see everything.

The problem is that I cannot seem to reference category.articles.  The goal is to filter the list of categories to not include categories with zero articles.

A category can have 0 to many articles.  An article will have only one category.

Here is my code.

```
const activeCategories = categories.filter((category) => {
    return category.articles.length > 0;
}
```

The editor tells me that "articles" does not exist on the category object.  It shows me the type of the categories and shows the only elements of categories is "id, parentId, name".

Why can't I reach "articles"?  They show up when I examine the categories object.  But not when I examine the individual "category" record.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my issue by modifying my query to include a filter at the query stage.  I still don't know the answer to the scenario I posted.  But this method did solve the application requirement.  I modified my query as follows:

```
const categories = await prisma.category.findMany(
    {
        where: {
            articles: {
                some: {
                    categoryId: {gt: 0}
                }
            }
        },
        include: {
            articles: true
        },
        orderBy: {
            name: 'asc'
        }
    }
);
```